# How to create new user in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am new to hadoop. I have done apache hadoop multinode installation and the user name is hadoop.
I am using total 3 nodes:  1 namenode and 2 datanodes

I have to create new user for data isolation. I have found few links on google, but those are not working and I am unable to access the hdfs.

```
**[user1@datanode1~]# hdfs dfs -ls -R /

bash: hdfs: command not found...**
```

Can someone help me with the steps to create the new user which can access hdfs for data isolation. And on which node I should create the new user.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like your _immediate_ problem is to set the Linux `PATH` for your additional user(s) so that the Hadoop commands are found automatically. Otherwise use the full path e.g. `/blah/blah/wtf/hdfs`.  Linux basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hadoop doesn't have users like Linux does. Users are generally managed by *external* LDAP/Kerberos systems. By default, there is not even security features, all user-names are based on the `HADOOP_USER_NAME` environment variable, and can be overriden by `export` command. Also, by default, the user used is the current username, for example, your command `user1@datanode1 # hdfs dfs -ls` would actually run `hdfs dfs -ls /user/user1`, and return an error if that folder doesn't first exist.

**However**, your actual error is saying that your OS `PATH` variable does not include `$HADOOP_HOME/bin`, for example. Edit your `.bashrc` to fix this.

You'd create an HDFS **folder** for "user" `username` with

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/username
hdfs dfs -chown username /user/username
hdfs dfs -chmod -R 770 /user/username
```

And you also should run `useradd` command on the namenode machine to make sure it knows about a user named "`username`"

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer .  I have addded $HADOOP_HOME/bin and $HADOOP_HOME/sbin in .bashrc file and gave permission on hadoop files. Now I am able to execute the hdfs commands. I will test few more scenario and update here.

Comment: In datanode1 I have created new user and gave 770 on directories and 660 on files in order to provide hdfs access to new user. Now I am able to access the hdfs but Now I am getting below error while stopping and starting the hadoop services on datanode1
datanode1: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
To resolve this I have to change the permission for hadoop home dir from 770 to 700 How can i resolve this without changing the permission everytime ?

Comment: @Shobit The error seems related to SSH. You shouldn't be changing local Unix `/home` folder permissions. HDFS also doesn't even look at datanode users, only namenode users (if configured to do so, which by default, I don't think it does). In any case, 660 means even the local user that owns the folder cannot browse directories, such as `.ssh`. 700 should be the minimum for the user home folder. The ssh folder should be 640 and your id_rsa files as 600